# How to change config in github workflows

Tags: .net, github, github-actions

My github workflow does not change web.*.config file for the environment I want to build.

My application is a .NET Framework 4.8, and I am using a self-hosted runner to build it.

The Build looks like this:

```
- name: Build Solution
  run: msbuild MySolution.sln /p:Configuration=Release /p:DeployOnBuild=true
```

And when I change configuration to e.g.; Test (Web.Test.Config), it does not replace the values. In order to solve this, I have used lots of environment variables, but I want these to be replaced on build rather than having them in my .yml file.

Any clue?

Comment: This should work indeed. Have you tested running this command from the commandline from the workflow folder (see _work)? If so the only thing that comes to mind is an additional environment setting that might be missing, not sure. Any insights into the configuration you switch with (in the sln or csproj files)?

Comment: In my Web.Test.Config I have the following:

<appsetting>
     <add key="test" value="test123" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
</appsetting>

Comment: And did you test it from the commandline already? What was the result?

Comment: It all went well. Is there a way where I can see my builded file?

Comment: Locally you can check the bin folder of course. With actions you can use a shell script to navigate to the folder and list what is in there, or upload the directory as an artefact, or just navigate to the directory on the runner itself if you have access.

Answer (score 0):

```
- name: Build Solution
  run: msbuild MySolution.sln /p:Configuration=Test /p:DeployOnBuild=true
```

Use `Test` in `p:Configuration=Test` instead of `p:Configuration=Release`.